Beards redo one's look?
Rashi comments in Parshas Mikeitz that the brothers didn't recongnize Yosef since he now had a beard, as opposed to how he left them - without a beard. I find this difficult to understand! Just because he had a beard, they couldn't recongize him!?! I understand he looked different, but not different enough to be unrecongnizable!?!?

I don't find this difficult to understand.

When you don't see someone for a while & now they've grown a beard - u probaly will still recongnize them (espicially if they're ur brother)

It was twenty (very long) years, plus the beard, and above all else -- they weren't expecting to see him there. People see what they want to see. (For those into comic books, here's a fun example: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_2_2)

I grew a beard while in EY.. it was very hard for my friends to recognize me. Only because I started talking to them as if I know them. And one friend (while i was talking to another) in mid conversation said. Ohh thats who you are.

The brothers were already in hot water with this Egyptian Official. Suppose they thought that he looked a bit like Joseph. If they asked him, and he wasn't Joseph, it would be an insane thing to say and the Egyptian would think they were crazy.
